# How can I manually configure the credentials for an CloudWatch agent on a non-EC2 Linux machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

How can I manually configure the credentials for a CloudWatch agent installed on a Ubuntu server, not running in AWS?

I downloaded this dep package for ubuntu and installed it on the server

```
wget https://amazoncloudwatch-agent.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
```

with

```
dpkg -i -E ./amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
```

I also started the

```
amazon-cloudwatch-agent-config-wizard
```

to generate a simple config.

```
./amazon-cloudwatch-agent-config-wizard 
================================================================
= Welcome to the Amazon CloudWatch Agent Configuration Manager =
=                                                              =
= CloudWatch Agent allows you to collect metrics and logs from =
= your host and send them to CloudWatch. Additional CloudWatch =
= charges may apply.                                           =
================================================================
On which OS are you planning to use the agent?
1. linux
2. windows
3. darwin
default choice: [1]:
1
Trying to fetch the default region based on ec2 metadata...
I! imds retry client will retry 1 timesD! should retry true for imds error : EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request
Not Found
    status code: 404, request id: D! should retry true for imds error : EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request
Not Found
    status code: 404, request id: 2023/11/03 10:03:42 D! could not get region from imds v2 thus enable fallback
2023/11/03 10:03:42 I! WARN: failed to get session token, falling back to IMDSv1: 404 Not Found: Not Found
    status code: 404, request id: 
caused by: EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request
Not Found
    status code: 404, request id: 
W! could not get region from ec2 metadata... EC2MetadataRequestError: failed to get EC2 instance identity document
caused by: EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request
Not Found
    status code: 404, request id: Are you using EC2 or On-Premises hosts?
1. EC2
2. On-Premises
default choice: [2]:
2
Please make sure the credentials and region set correctly on your hosts.
Refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
Which user are you planning to run the agent?
1. root
2. cwagent
3. others
default choice: [1]:
1
Do you want to turn on StatsD daemon?
1. yes
2. no
default choice: [1]:
2
Do you want to monitor metrics from CollectD? WARNING: CollectD must be installed or the Agent will fail to start
1. yes
2. no
default choice: [1]:
2
Do you want to monitor any host metrics? e.g. CPU, memory, etc.
1. yes
2. no
default choice: [1]:
1
Do you want to monitor cpu metrics per core?
1. yes
2. no
default choice: [1]:
1
Would you like to collect your metrics at high resolution (sub-minute resolution)? This enables sub-minute resolution for all metrics, but you can customize for specific metrics in the output json file.
1. 1s
2. 10s
3. 30s
4. 60s
default choice: [4]:
2
Which default metrics config do you want?
1. Basic
2. Standard
3. Advanced
4. None
default choice: [1]:
2
Current config as follows:
{
    "agent": {
        "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
        "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "metrics": {
        "metrics_collected": {
            "cpu": {
                "measurement": [
                    "cpu_usage_idle",
                    "cpu_usage_iowait"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ],
                "totalcpu": true
            },
            "disk": {
                "measurement": [
                    "used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "diskio": {
                "measurement": [
                    "io_time",
                    "write_bytes",
                    "read_bytes",
                    "writes",
                    "reads"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "mem": {
                "measurement": [
                    "mem_used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10
            },
            "net": {
                "measurement": [
                    "bytes_sent",
                    "bytes_recv",
                    "packets_sent",
                    "packets_recv"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "swap": {
                "measurement": [
                    "swap_used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
Are you satisfied with the above config? Note: it can be manually customized after the wizard completes to add additional items.
1. yes
2. no
default choice: [1]:
1
Do you have any existing CloudWatch Log Agent (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) configuration file to import for migration?
1. yes
2. no
default choice: [2]:
2
Do you want to monitor any log files?
1. yes
2. no
default choice: [1]:
2
Do you want the CloudWatch agent to also retrieve X-ray traces?
1. yes
2. no
default choice: [1]:
2
Existing config JSON identified and copied to:  /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/backup-configs
Saved config file to /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json successfully.
Current config as follows:
{
    "agent": {
        "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
        "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "metrics": {
        "metrics_collected": {
            "cpu": {
                "measurement": [
                    "cpu_usage_idle",
                    "cpu_usage_iowait"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ],
                "totalcpu": true
            },
            "disk": {
                "measurement": [
                    "used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "diskio": {
                "measurement": [
                    "io_time",
                    "write_bytes",
                    "read_bytes",
                    "writes",
                    "reads"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "mem": {
                "measurement": [
                    "mem_used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10
            },
            "net": {
                "measurement": [
                    "bytes_sent",
                    "bytes_recv",
                    "packets_sent",
                    "packets_recv"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "swap": {
                "measurement": [
                    "swap_used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
Please check the above content of the config.
The config file is also located at /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json.
Edit it manually if needed.
Do you want to store the config in the SSM parameter store?
1. yes
2. no
default choice: [1]:
2
Program exits now.
```

How can I configure authentication without installing the AWS CLI, or is it really needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the AWS CLI is not *needed* to run the CloudWatch Agent.

It works separately & independently however it's ideal as you *can* use `aws configure` to [set up](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html#install-CloudWatch-Agent-iam_user-first) the config & credentials for the agent.

If you don't want to use the AWS CLI, follow these steps:

1. Create a folder called `.aws` in your home directory (`~/.aws`)

```bash
mkdir ~./aws
```

2. Create a file called `config` in this directory ([`~/.aws/config`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/file-location.html)) using the below commands, replacing the value for `region` with the destination for your logs.

```bash
cd ~./aws
touch config

region="eu-west-1"

echo "[AmazonCloudWatchAgent]
region = $region" > config
```

```bash
➜  ~ cat config
[AmazonCloudWatchAgent]
region = eu-west-1
```

3. Create a file called `credentials` in this directory ([`~/.aws/credentials`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/file-location.html)) using the below commands, replacing `aws_access_key_id` & `aws_secret_access_key` with your respective credentials.

```bash
touch credentials

access_key="xxx"
secret_key="yyy"

echo "[AmazonCloudWatchAgent]
aws_access_key_id = $access_key
aws_secret_access_key = $secret_key" > credentials
```

```bash
➜  ~ cat credentials
[AmazonCloudWatchAgent]
aws_access_key_id = xxx
aws_secret_access_key = yyy
```

4. [Restart the CloudWatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/troubleshooting-CloudWatch-Agent.html#CloudWatch-Agent-troubleshooting-stopping-restarting)

---

Note that you're running the agent as the `root` user here, as you specified `1` as the answer to this question:

```
Which user are you planning to run the agent?
1. root
2. cwagent
3. others
```

This then sets the `run_as_user` field in the config JSON (`/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json`).

To run it as any other user other than `root` or `cwagent`, select `3` which prompts you for a username, or alternatively manually change the `run_as_user` field in the JSON yourself.

Ensure the `config` and `credentials` files exist in the correct home directory i.e. `/home/{username}/.aws/credentials`.

Comment: Hi Ermiya, the wizard did not ask me for any credentials: "it would have asked you for AWS credentials to use"
I have not installed AWS CLI and would like to use the agent without AWS CLI.
I updated my question with the output auf the wizard. What did I wrong?

Comment: @PhilippS. Apologies, the documentation is indeed [incorrect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-cloudwatch-agent-configuration-file-wizard.html) in this regard and I was relying on it without manually verifying ('If you choose Others, you can input credentials'). I will flag this with the AWS team. I've reworded my answer if that now helps?

Comment: Thank you! It is working now. Is it also possible to run the agent on a server without root?

Comment: @PhilippS. No worries :) yes it is - updated the footnote of the answer.

Comment: I mean running it on a server without any root access. We have some managed vservers without root access. I am wondering if I could install and run the agent on this kind of server as well?

Comment: Yes - as long as you specify which user to use (which can be non-root) in the config. The key is the config and credentials file; the actual user it runs under is up to you. If you don't specify `run_as_user` it will run as root, otherwise it will run as the non-root user you have specified e.g. `my-non-root-user`. Does that help?

Comment: I am not sure how I can install the agent on the system without root. Can I install the agent into home home folder? I can not find anything in the docs regarding the agent as a normal user?